# Import XML in Access Table

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I'm illiterate in XML but need to import a dataset from a 3rd party into a Microsoft Access table. What I'd like as the end result is something like this:

[Desired Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1DKx.png)

Opening the XML directly through Excel shows as three worksheets like below, but I only need the data from MetaInfo and CustomInfo:

[Excel Current Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zscKf.png)

Running a direct import using the built-in function in Access results in several tables. Two of these have the data I need, but it's formatted wrong and has field names as record rows.

[Access Built-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwvfq.png)

I'd like to accomplish this through VBA ultimately, tying it to a button to allow the user to select a file downloaded to disk from the 3rd party software.

The XML file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>13845</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>28800</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>32767</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>32767</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy/dd/mm\ hh:mm:ss"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="MetaInfo">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="4" ss:ExpandedRowCount="28" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:Width="80.25"/>
   <Column ss:Width="125.25"/>
   <Column ss:Width="82.5"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">UniqueReportId</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">UniqueMetaInfoId</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Text</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Unit</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">TESTED BY</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ZIP</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">DATE</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">02/21/2022</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SENT TO</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">53</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PLANT</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">4</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">F.O.NO.</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B7861</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">LENGTH</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">3364</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ft</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CUSTOMER</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CUMBERLAND</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PHASE</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SINGLE</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">DESCRIPTION</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">3/C #15 SOMETHING</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CABLE NO.</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">438123A</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CABLE RATING</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">75</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">kV</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SPECIFICATION</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PL SPEC</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">N/A</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Unsynced/>
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>27</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>2</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="CustomInfo">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="7" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">UniqueReportId</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">UniqueCustomInfoId</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Text</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PDReport</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Field2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Unsynced/>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: That's an XML format Excel workbook - ideally you use Excel to open that: don't parse it as "pure" XML unless you want to do a lot of work.

Comment: Can i execute that Excel process through Access and transform the rows to columns? I'm not sure how otherwise. The DoCmd.TransferSpreadSheet function in Access gives error 3274: External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: Did you try different format arguments?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acspreadsheettype

Comment: I've tried 9, 12, and 12Xml. I've also tried these with just changing the file extension between xml, xls, and xlsx.

Comment: You could automate Excel to re-save the file in a useable format.

Comment: I think you're onto something, Tim.  I think I can create an Excel XLSM file that contains the necessary macro(s) to open the XML file, run some copy/paste/transpose tasks and save it as an XLSX file.  Then I can directly import that into my Access table.

Comment: You can also automate Excel directly from Access.

Comment: Is there a way to pass variables from an Access module to Excel and back through VBA?  What I've done so far is move most of the code to an Excel xlsm file and having Access just open that file and execute the Excel macro that contains a rename of the XML to xlsx.  Access will then just perform a transferspreadsheet.  This is working well so far.  I plan to post the results when complete.

Comment: Are you using Application.Run to run the Excel macro?  If No what are you using?  If Yes, you can pass arguments and get a return value (if you're calling a function).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run#:~:text=The%20Run%20method%20returns%20whatever%20the%20called%20macro%20returns

Comment: I'm using this in Access to open the Excel spreadsheet and run the macro that does the rest.      
    Dim xlapp As Object
        Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    With xlapp
        
        .workbooks.Open xlfilename
        .Run "ChartImport"
        .activeworkbook.Close (True)
        .Quit
    
    End With

Comment: If you need to add details or code you can edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75802443/edit   It's much easier to read there.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the simplest solution so far, but I'll keep playing with it. I moved most of the work over to Excel and am now just calling Excel from my Access database and specifying a macro.

Tim picked up that the XML file was and XML formatted Excel workbook, so I was able to just tell Excel to open up the XML file and save it as an XLSX file and perform some copy/paste of the data to clean it up for Access to do a simple transferspreadsheet.

Access:

```
Dim xlfilename As String
xlfilename = "C:\LDIC\XMLConvert.xlsm"
Dim xlsheetname As String

Dim xlapp As Object
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xlapp
    
    .workbooks.Open xlfilename
    .Run "ChartImport"
    .activeworkbook.Close (True)
    .Quit

End With

Set xlapp = Nothing

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tblMeta", "C:\LDIC\ChartInfo.xlsx", True, "A1:AI2"
```

In Excel, I have to find the newest subfolder and file within that folder based on the way the 3rd party software is exporting the XML file I want to import. Here's the Excel macro that does that and formats the data for import into Access:

```
'****************** Find newest path and file ********************
Dim FileName As String
Dim MostRecentFile As String
Dim MostRecentDate As Date
Dim FileSpec As String
Dim sPath, sDir As String

Dim FSO, FS, F, DtLast As Date, Result As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FS = FSO.GetFolder("c:\LDIC\").SubFolders
    For Each F In FS
        If F.DateLastModified > DtLast Then
             DtLast = F.DateLastModified
             Result = F.Name
        End If
    Next

'Specify the file type, if any
 FileSpec = "*.xml"
'specify the directory
sDir = "C:\LDIC\" & Result & "\"
Directory = sDir
FileName = Dir(Directory & FileSpec)

If FileName <> "" Then
    MostRecentFile = FileName
    MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If FileDateTime(Directory & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
             MostRecentFile = FileName
             MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
        End If
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
End If

'Check that latest XML file is the expected file
If Not InStr(1, MostRecentFile, "PDMeas") Then
    MsgBox "Could not find XML data file", vbCritical, "File Not Found"
    GoTo ExitHere
End If

'Successfully found file so resume work
sPath = Directory & MostRecentFile

'Open 3rd party XML data file, copy custom fields to main worksheet, transpose columns to rows,
'delete unnecessary info, rename column headers that Access cannot import, and save as XLSX file
ChDir sDir
Workbooks.Open FileName:=sPath
Sheets("CustomInfo").Select
Range("A1:C7").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("MetaInfo").Select
Range("A29").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1:D35").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("F1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Columns("A:E").Select
Range("E1").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("3:3").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "FO"
Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "QC"
Range("L1").Select
ChDir "C:\LDIC"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\LDIC\ChartInfo.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```